# Using Stripe.net, how to retrieve items from a successful charge response body?

Tags: asp.net, stripe-payments, stripe.net

Using the Stripe.net service API (https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net), how can you retrieve an item from a successful charge's response body?

Example of successful charge response body:

```
{
id: ch_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
object: "charge",
created: 111111111,
livemode: true,
paid: true,
status: "succeeded",
amount: 33400,
currency: "usd",
refunded: false,
source:
    {
    id: card_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
    object: "card",
    last4: "1234",
    brand: "Visa",
    funding: "credit",
    exp_month: 12,
    exp_year: 2010,
    fingerprint: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    country: "BR",
    name: "john smith",
    address_line1: "address 1",
    address_line2: null,
    address_city: "senai",
    address_state: null,
    address_zip: "00000",
    address_country: "MY",
    cvc_check: "pass",
    address_line1_check: "unavailable",
    address_zip_check: "unavailable",
    tokenization_method: null,
    dynamic_last4: null,
    metadata:
    {},
    customer: null
}
captured: true,
balance_transaction: "txn_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
...
```

I am simply trying to get the values of the following:

```
address_line1_check: "unavailable",
address_zip_check: "unavailable",
```

For those curious as to why, simply that when those two values are "unavailable", it means the Bank's credit card does not support these anti-fraud features and from experience there are a high chance these charges are indeed fraudulent.  Therefore, once I detect them, I can add a red flag on those transactions.

Best if no need to make changes to the Stripe.net API...

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a charge with Stripe.net it returns a StripeCharge object with properties for accessing the values returned from the Stripe API.

For example:

```
var chargeService = new StripeChargeService();
StripeCharge stripeCharge = chargeService.Create(myCharge);
string status = stripeCharge.Status;
```

One of the properties of the StripeCharge object is Source which is a StripeCard. The StripeCard class has properties for AddressLine1Check and AddressZipCheck which correspond to the JSON properties you want. So you should be able to get the values you want like this:

```
string addressLine1Check = stripeCharge.Source.AddressLine1Check;
string addressZipCheck = stripeCharge.Source.AddressZipCheck;
```

For the class definitions (to see all the properties) see https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net/blob/master/src/Stripe/Entities/StripeCharge.cs and https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net/blob/master/src/Stripe/Entities/StripeCard.cs

Comment: Will it be returning the Credit card Name and Address even if we do not pass it in the the token ?

Comment: @CodeIt no, based on what I see in the stripe logs of my account, it does not.